# Windows 10 64-bit: All installers hang at the start, doing nothing

Tags: windows-10, installer

System: Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit
Computer: HP ZBook G 15

After a failed installation of a crappy application (google calendar sync), my Win 10 system is now blocked from installing - apparently - antyhing.

All application installers I try start, and then it hangs forever (literally, not being slow, but never starting) at the start, with no progress whatsoever. They use no system resources, and do nothing. And they cannot be closed; Clicking cancel or similar does absolutely nothing. One or two could be killed in TaskManager, but most cannot - they disappear from the task lists, but the non-responsive installation window never vanishes from the desktop.

Any ideas? This used to be a "reinstall windows" kind of problem, but I'm not interested in spending the next two days reinstalling and setting up my system again for something as stupid as this.

Process Monitor shows the following (that is, absolutely nothing of value):

[image]

Nothing more happens. At all. Ever.

And yes, of course I've tried restarting. More than once.

Comment: I've also had this problem on numerous occations, mostly in Windows 7. I've never gotten anywhere, and no matter who I ask no one - MS experts or other - seems to even understand the problem. 

(Sorry - this wasn't very helpful, just meant as moral support.)

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: [How to troubleshoot Windows Installer errors](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2438651/how-to-troubleshoot-windows-installer-errors)

Comment: DavidPostill: Those tips are not relevant, as they all are about error messages. As I'm trying to describe, there are no errors - nothing happens - the installers won't start.

Comment: This is exactly what I mean when I say that experts doesn't even seem to understand the question/problem...

Comment: Try and do a "sfc /scannow" without the Parentheses in a CMD window running as Administrator and see if it can see if there are any problems it can fix.

Comment: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Answer (score 0):

In my condition when I get similar problem I install the applications by pressing `Right Click` on the file and `Run as Administrator`. Mostly it will run in that method when application doesn't even start or install when using normal method like `Double Click`.

If that still doesn't help then I use third party softwares like [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) portable and remove remaining trace of failed install application(in your case `Google Calendar Sync`) by doing forced uninstall.

After this I mostly clean temp files and folders and registry or simply use [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download). With this I was almost always able to fix the problem and install applications that I want. Hope it will also help it to you.

Comment: I've tried installing as Administrator - doesn't do any difference. I'll look at revo uninstaller.

Comment: I've tried installing as Administrator - doesn't do any difference. Revo uninstaller (portable) doesn't list Google Calendar Sync, so it's apparently not installed at all (which rhymes with the fact that the installers doesn't even begin the installations). Not sure how to search for other incomplete/failed installations? CCcleaner is impossible, because it has to be installed, and no installers can be run.

Comment: in pro portable version there is `force uninstall` option where you can search the failed installed applications by keyword and remove all the traces. As for CCleaner you can install in your USB in another computer if you have and use it

Comment: Normally for CCleaner I use it through Hiren's Boot CD. So it is portable version for me. Sorry, for not being great help.

Comment: Also, If you have additional PC then you can install trial license of Revo Pro in USB and use it in your problem computer. That is all the idea that I can come up with.

Comment: You can always use `System Restore` and revert back to previous condition of your computer without issues if you have enabled it.

Comment: All help is welcome, so don't apologize :-) As for the force uninstall option, I cannot find anything like it in the free version.

Comment: Maybe you wanna [try this](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1875807/installer-windows-installer-hangs-install.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57674/discussion-between-biku-balami-and-hfrav).